# Examine whether a linear map is continuous and determine the operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, normed-spaces

Let $P$ be the space of all real-valued polynomials, defined on $\mathbb{R}$. For a polynomial $p\in P$, such that $p(t)= \sum_{k=0}^na_kt^k$, set $||p||:= \sum_{k=0}^n|a_k|$. Consider the linear mappings $f_i : P \to \mathbb{R}, i = 1, ..., 3$, which are given by

$f_1(p)= \int_0^1p(t)dt $ , $f_2(p)= p'(0) $, $f_3(p)= p'(1) $

Examine for $i=1, ..., 3$ whether $f_i$ is continuous and determine the operator norm $||f_i||$

Since this is a homework, I would love to solve it by myself but am really having trouble with how to start since I'm not used to this type of exercise. What I have been thinking of so far is: if $f_i$ is countinous, I should show that it is bounded (but don't really know how), else I should find some point where I can show a counterexample. Is this the right way to solve this exercise? Any hint would be really appreciated!

Comment: Showing that they are bounded seems like a good start. Why don’t you write down what boundedness means for each $f_i$ and see whether this is satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I'll show an example with $f_1$. Let $p=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$. Then:

$|f_1(p)|=|\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^kdx|=|\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\int_0^1 x^kdx|=|\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{k+1}|\leq\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|=||p||$

Since this is true for all $p\in P$ we proved that the functional is bounded (which is equivalent to continuous) and its norm is at most $1$. It makes sense to believe that the norm is equal to $1$. And this is true, because if we take $p=1$ (the constant polynomial $1$) then it is easy to check that $\frac{|f_1(p)|}{||p||}=1$. So the norm of $f_1$ is at least $1$.

Now try to do the same thing with $f_2$ and $f_3$.

Comment: It seems the OP already knows they need to show that the maps are bounded. What they’re really asking is how to do that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't understand the problem correctly. Well, I edited my answer and made it more relevant.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for giving the example :). For $f_2$, I would say $|f_2|=|a_1|\le||p||$ so $f_2$ is continuous. And $f_3$ is not continuous since $f_3(p) = p'(1) = |\sum_{k=1}^na_kk|\ge||p||$ so it's not bounded and hence not continuous.

Comment: But I don't really get how one would compute the operator norm. It is supposed to be the smallest $C$, such that $|f|\le C||p|| $, right?

Comment: You are right about $f_2$. Now about $f_3$: in general, if $|f_3(p)|\geq ||p||$ it is still not enough to prove that the functional is not bounded. The definition of bounded is that there is some $M>0$ such that $|f_3(p)|\leq M||p||$ for all $p\in P$, and $M$ might be bigger than $1$. So to prove it is not bounded you need to show that no $M$ works. If you want I can give a hint on how to do that.

Comment: Yes, this is a possible definition of the operator norm. An equivalent definition is $||f||=\sup_{p\ne 0}\frac{|f(p)|}{||p||}$. So for $f_1$ I first showed that for each $0\ne p\in P$ we have $\frac{|f_1(p)|}{||p||}\leq 1$. This proves the supremum is at most $1$. Then I found a specific $p$ such that $\frac{|f_1(p)|}{||p||}=1$, hence the supremum can't be less than $1$. So in this example it was not just a supremum, but even a maximum. (this is not always the case)

Comment: @Mark So $||f_2||$ is also $1$ and we can choose $p(t) = 0 + a_1t$ so $1$ is the maximum ? and yes, could you please give a hint for $f_3$? :)

Comment: Yes, this is correct. As for $f_3$ look at the sequence of polynomials $p_n(t)=t^n$. What is $\frac{|f_3(p_n)|}{||p_n||}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: If $p_n(t)=t^n$ then $\frac{|f_3(p_n)|}{||p_n||}=n$ hence, $|f_3(p_n)|=n||p_n||$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} $ and this implies that no matter which $n$ we choose, we can't have $|f_3(p_n)|\le n||p_n||$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In other words for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $p\in P$ such that $|f_3(p)|\geq n||p||$. And this of course implies that $f_3$ is not bounded.

Comment: @Mark I get it now. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: You're welcome.